# How to Silent Login with NextAuth?

Tags: next.js13

I'd like to implement a silent login using nextAuth. I'm new to the Next and its Authentication. Currently in my implementation I'm using the credentials provider with the credentials object empty.

```
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {},
```

This produces a login page with a button that you need to click to authorize. I would like the user to never see or skip the login page and just automatically log them in. My authorize function looks like this

```
async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const cookieStore = cookies();
         
          const sessionId = cookieStore.get(
            process.env.DRUPAL_GB_SESSION_COOKIE ?? ""
          );

          const sessionData = await fetch(
            `${process.env.API_URL}?id=${sessionId?.value}&key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
            {
              next: { revalidate: 10 },
            }
          );

          const drupalData = await sessionData.json();
          const { get_current_user: userData } = drupalData;
          
          if (userData.uid.length > 0) {
        
            return userData;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (err: any) {
          throw new Error("CredentialsSignin");
        }
      },
```

I'm also using callback, the jwt and the session.

```
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, profile }) {
      if (user) {
       
        token.firstname = user.firstname;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.firstname = token.firstname;
      return session;
    },
  },
```

I have my assumptions that you might be able to do something in middleware. Perhaps this is the wrong approach but looking for some advice and possible solutions. Thanks!